# Ruby thread terminates abruptly when using rest-client

Tags: ruby

Here's a hopefully final attempt at this post:

When I try to make a call using rest-client in a thread, it fails and leaves the thread early. When I run it outside of the thread, it's fine.

Any ideas?

```
require 'base64'
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'
require 'thwait'

test = Thread.new {
    endpoint = "http://my/url"
    headers = {'Authorization' => "Basic #{Base64.encode64("username:password")}", 'Accept' => 'Application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'Application/json'}
    payload = JSON.parse("{\"documents\": { \"textField1\":\"asdf\" }}").to_json

    # See the results of the above. Successful now (headers hash with expected encoded value, JSON string as expected)
    puts headers
    puts payload

    # Expecting REST response on the console. Nothing appears on the console.
    puts RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => endpoint, :headers => headers, :payload => payload, :verify_ssl => false)
    # Expecting simple text output to the console to see if execution reaches this point. Nothing appears on the console.
    puts 'done'
}

# Where this is actually being used, ThreadsWait is used for thread management, so simulating that here
thwait = ThreadsWait.new(test)
thwait.next_wait
```

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that running some piece of code in a thread causes the entire Ruby process to crash. If that's the case then you must include that code in your example. If you don't include the code that induces a crash, how can we tell what's going wrong?

Comment: I was wrong, it is the thread that stops. The stuff generally alluded to is so simple that I thought it didn't matter, but I'll post examples.

Comment: Can we see the code and the error detail. Even if it’s in the thread it’ll appear in the logs.

Comment: Code snippets posted above. I'm getting nothing on the console- what logs are you referring to?

Comment: Can you please clarify your examples? **Be specific**: "I run this exact code by doing _z_ and I expect _x_ to happen but instead _y_ happens." Just including a comment that says `# No result` is not specific enough, and it's unclear how example 2 and 3 relate to example 1.

Comment: Hopefully clarified

Answer (score 0):

You need to `join` the thread to see the output.  If you don't join it before the main thread terminates, then it will kill it ([see docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Thread.html)).

```
require 'rest-client'
endpoint = "/my/url"
headers = {'Authorization' => "Basic #{Base64.encode64("mycreds")}", 'Accept' => 'Application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'Application/json'}
payload = JSON.parse("{\"documents\": { \"textField1\":\"asdf\" }}").to_json
test_thread = Thread.new {
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :post, :url => endpoint, :headers => headers, :payload => payload, :verify_ssl => false)
    puts response
}.join
```

Comment: Yeah, I botched this a bit taking it out of context. Attempting original post again. Not my day.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Ruby 2.5.7 and rest-client version 2.0.2.  After I upgraded to rest-client version 2.1.0 the problem went away.  The older version of rest-client ran fine on Ruby 2.3.1.